# Rails 4.0 Record not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested

I have a Opportunity Model that has many Links. Links is a nested resource of Opportunity. On my views/opportunities/show.html.erb page, I display all the links that belong to that opportunity and I rendered a "new link" form as well. This form worked fine until recently and I am not sure why. When I fill out the "new link" form and click "add", the record does not save. Could someone please help me with this?

Here is my views/opportunities/show.html.erb page:

```
  <%= render @opportunity %>
  <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend>Links</legend>
    <div id="links">
      <%= render @opportunity.links %>
    </div>
    <%= render :file => 'links/new' %>

   </fieldset>
 </form>
```

Here is my views/links/new page:

```
   <%= form_for ([@opportunity, @opportunity.links.new]) do |f| %>


        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "Description:" %> <br />
            <%= f.text_field :description %> 
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <%= f.label "URL:" %> <br />
            <%= f.text_field :link_url %> 
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <%= f.submit 'Add' %> 
        </div>

    <% end %>
```

Here is my create link controller:

```
def create

  @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])
  @link = @opportunity.links.new(link_params)
    if @link.save
      redirect_to @opportunity, notice: 'link has been added'
    else
      redirect_to @opportunity, alert: 'Unable to add link'
    end
  end
```

Here is my Link model:

```
 class Link < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :opportunity

 end
```

Here is my Opportunity model:

```
class Opportunity < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :links
end
```

Here is the code from my console:

```
Started GET "/opportunities/7?utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=ZLgPz98w2MjTChzzDXJ8EcqNmYNtBUG5DSYcp1CXReU%3D&link%5Bdescription%5D=testlink&link%5Blink_url%5D=testlink&commit=Add" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-02 15:19:06 -0400
Processing by OpportunitiesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"ZLgPz98w2MjTChzzDXJ8EcqNmYNtBUG5DSYcp1CXReU=", "link"=>{"description"=>"testlink", "link_url"=>"testlink"}, "commit"=>"Add", "id"=>"7"}
  Opportunity Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "opportunities".* FROM "opportunities"  WHERE "opportunities"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 7]]
  Rendered opportunities/_opportunity.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Link Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "links".* FROM "links"  WHERE "links"."opportunity_id" = ?  [["opportunity_id", 7]]
  Rendered links/_link.html.erb (0.2ms)
  Rendered links/new.html.erb (2.0ms)
```

Comment: How does your model look like? Rails has issues displaying the opportunities. Can you put the code of your model and are your db migrations ok>

Comment: I edited to add my models. I deleted all the migration files awhile ago @HristoGeorgiev

Comment: Where is your `form_for`? It looks like you're performing a `GET` request on form submit, when you should be performing a `POST`.

Comment: @DamienRoche I edited so it's there now. It wasn't there before because I didn't enter enough tabs... Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to debug it. I would start with adding the gem [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) to your project.
Then you should temporarily change your code to something like:

```
def create

  @opportunity = Opportunity.find(params[:opportunity_id])
  @link = @opportunity.links.new(link_params)
    if @link.save
      redirect_to @opportunity, notice: 'link has been added'
    else
      binding.pry
      redirect_to @opportunity, alert: 'Unable to add link'
    end
end
```

In order to test it, you perform the add link action as usual. The code processing will stop at the line where `binding.pry` is being called. I assume here that the saving of therecord fails and we enter `else` part of the condition.

If I assume correctly, the `link` variable will be enriched with `errors`. In the console prompt of `binding.pry` just try to display them, if there are any (`@link.errors`)

I hope that helps.